# Problem in Delete data in table (Java Swing)

Tags: java, database, swing, jtable

I made 2 java classes, one to save information in MySQL database and another one to display this data.

Both class work perfect , but I made a delete button in display class to delete data from the table and the database, it's don't delete it and there is no error showing.

This is my code.

```
package finallibrary;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.sql.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;
import net.proteanit.sql.DbUtils;

public class StudentDetails extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    private JPanel contentPane;
    private JTable table;
    private JTextField search;
    private JButton b1, b2, b3;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new StudentDetails().setVisible(true);
    }

    public void student() {
        try {
            Conn con = new Conn();
            String sql = "select * from student";
            PreparedStatement st = con.c.prepareStatement(sql);
            ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery();

            table.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
            rs.close();
            st.close();
            con.c.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }

    public StudentDetails() {
        setTitle("Student List");
        setBounds(350, 200, 890, 475);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBackground(new Color(220, 220, 220));
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        contentPane.setLayout(null);

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
        scrollPane.setBounds(34, 133, 805, 273);
        contentPane.add(scrollPane);

        table = new JTable();
        table.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
                int row = table.getSelectedRow();
                search.setText(table.getModel().getValueAt(row, 1).toString());
            }
        });
        table.setBackground(new Color(240, 248, 255));
        table.setForeground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
        table.setFont(new Font("Trebuchet MS", Font.BOLD, 16));
        scrollPane.setViewportView(table);

        JButton b1 = new JButton("Search");
        b1.addActionListener(this);
        b1.setFont(new Font("Trebuchet MS", Font.BOLD, 18));
        b1.setBounds(524, 89, 144, 33);
        contentPane.add(b1);

        JButton b2 = new JButton("Delete");
        b2.addActionListener(this);
        b2.setFont(new Font("Trebuchet MS", Font.BOLD, 18));
        b2.setBounds(695, 89, 144, 33);
        contentPane.add(b2);

        JLabel l1 = new JLabel("Student List");
        l1.setFont(new Font("Bookman Old Style", Font.BOLD, 26));
        l1.setBounds(250, 20, 400, 47);
        contentPane.add(l1);

        search = new JTextField();
        search.setFont(new Font("Trebuchet MS", Font.BOLD, 17));
        search.setBounds(158, 89, 306, 33);
        contentPane.add(search);
        search.setColumns(10);

        JButton b3 = new JButton("Back");
        b3.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                setVisible(false);
                Home home = new Home();
                home.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
        b3.setForeground(Color.GRAY);
        b3.setFont(new Font("Trebuchet MS", Font.BOLD, 18));
        b3.setBounds(34, 89, 100, 33);
        contentPane.add(b3);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBorder(new TitledBorder(new LineBorder(new Color(95, 158, 160), 3, true), "Student-List",
                TitledBorder.LEADING, TitledBorder.TOP, null, new Color(72, 209, 204)));
        panel.setBounds(10, 59, 848, 370);
        panel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        contentPane.add(panel);

        student();
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        try {

            Conn con = new Conn();
            if (ae.getSource() == b1) {
                String sql = "select * from student where concat(name, student_id) like ?";
                PreparedStatement st = con.c.prepareStatement(sql);
                st.setString(1, "%" + search.getText() + "%");
                ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery();

                table.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
                rs.close();
                st.close();
            }

            if (ae.getSource() == b2) {
                String sql = "delete from student where name = '" + search.getText() + "'";
                PreparedStatement st = con.c.prepareStatement(sql);

                JDialog.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
                int response = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Do you want to continue?", "Confirm",
                        JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
                if (response == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION) {

                } else if (response == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
                    int rs = st.executeUpdate();
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Deleted !!");
                } else if (response == JOptionPane.CLOSED_OPTION) {

                }
                st.close();

            }
            con.c.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to reload the data for the `TableModel`

Comment: *"there is no error showing"* Not surprising given code like this `catch (Exception e) { }` - always called `e.printStackTrace();` in the `catch` (unless logging is implemented).

Comment: i tried but same result

Comment: *it's don't delete it* - where doesn't it delete it. a) from the database or b) from the JTable or c) both.  *i tried but same result*  - where. I don't see changes to your code. How can we tell if you implemented the suggestion correctly? Your logic to select the data from the database and populate your JTable should be in a method so you can invoke the method in multiple places. This way if it works in one place it should work in the other.